# Remove header style from gridview export to excel

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is there a way I can remove the gridview's header style and width before exporting to excel?

Here is my current export function

```
        Response.Clear();
        Response.Charset = "";
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", String.Format("attachment;filename={0}",    "     ExportData.xls"));

        // Prompt for Open/Save/Cancel
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Private);
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";

        System.IO.StringWriter stringWrite = new System.IO.StringWriter();

        System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter htmlWrite =
        new HtmlTextWriter(stringWrite);

        GridView1.RenderControl(htmlWrite);

        Response.Write(stringWrite.ToString());


        Response.End();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can customize the headerstyle for the gridview before exporting. Here is the sample code on how you can do it.

```
var gv = new GridView();
gv.DataSource = reportdata;
gv.DataBind();

// style the header
gv.HeaderRow.Height = Unit.Pixel(35);
gv.HeaderRow.Cells[0].Text = "Some custom header text";
gv.HeaderRow.Cells[0].Width = Unit.Pixel(400);

for (int col = 0; col < gv.HeaderRow.Controls.Count; col++)
{
    TableCell tc = gv.HeaderRow.Cells[col];
    tc.Style.Add("color", "#FFFFFF");
    tc.Style.Add("background-color", "#444");
    tc.Style.Add("border-color", bordercolor);
}

// And your code as follows

Response.Clear();
Response.Charset = "";
Response.Buffer = true;
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", String.Format("attachment;filename={0}",    "     ExportData.xls"));

// Prompt for Open/Save/Cancel
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Private);
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";

System.IO.StringWriter stringWrite = new System.IO.StringWriter();
System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter htmlWrite =
     new HtmlTextWriter(stringWrite);

gv.RenderControl(htmlWrite);

Response.Write(stringWrite.ToString());
Response.End();
```

Answer (score 1):

What I have done is to simply initiate a new GridView and populate it with the same data when I print to Excel. That way you can have a separate design for the Excel file.

Answer (score 0):

Put `GridView` in a div say `divgrid` (class name is divgrid) and use following css to hide header while printing.

```
<style media="print">
    .divgrid thead {
        display: none;
    }
   .divgrid th{
        display: none;
    }
</style>
```